# Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-fold-env

Tags: emacs

latex-mode loaded when I open .tex file but when I try to use "latex-fold" function it shows

```
Symbol's function definition is void: Tex-fold-env
```

When I use function Describe Variable C-h v 'TeX-fold-env-spec-list' then
move back to .tex buffer by selecting it, then use "latex-fold" function, the error is gone and it works perfectly.

Why is this happening?
did describe variable trigger some mode? how to know which mode is that?

I already tried to use Tex-mode, tex-mode, Latex-mode, latex-mode, but none of them worked.

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate, but I don't have the time now to search...

Answer (score 0):

After some minutes try each tex{...}mode, load TeX-fold-mode fix this problem

```
;; automatically load TeX-fold-mode
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tex\\'" . TeX-fold-mode))
```

Comment: as that is an autoloaded *minor* mode, you may want to put it in your mode hook, `(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'TeX-fold-mode)`.  Only the first matching element from `auto-mode-alist` will be used to determine the major mode